# How to find top rows based on max coulmn and group by another coulmn?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have this table (simplified version):

| id | state | place | temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | PLC1 | 10 |
| 2 | AA | PLC2 | 20 |
| 3 | AA | PLC3 | 25 |
| 4 | EE | PLC4 | 11 |
| 5 | EE | PLC5 | 15 |
| 6 | EE | PLC6 | 19 |
| . | .. | .... | .. |

**How to find top 2 hottest places (based on temp column) from X states ?**
The states will be provided during query time, i.e there may be 2 or 5 states which is not known in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to find top 2 hottest places (based on temp column) from X states
> ? The states will be provided during query time, i.e there may be 2 or
> 5 states which is not known in advance.

The following query shall give you the desired result

```
SELECT t1.state, t1.place, t1.temp
FROM table_name t1
WHERE t1.state IN ('state1', 'state2', ...)
  AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table_name t2
    WHERE t2.state = t1.state AND t2.temp >= t1.temp
  ) <= 2
ORDER BY t1.state, t1.temp DESC;
```

Here is the [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2651f1/1) using your sample data.

The query :

```
SELECT t1.state, t1.place, t1.temp
FROM table_name t1
WHERE t1.state IN ('AA', 'EE')
  AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table_name t2
    WHERE t2.state = t1.state AND t2.temp >= t1.temp
  ) <= 2
ORDER BY t1.state, t1.temp DESC;
```

Returns correct output as :

```
state   place   temp
AA      PLC3    25
AA      PLC2    20
EE      PLC6    19
EE      PLC5    15
```

The query can be also written using `ROW_NUMBER` with `PARTITION BY` clause as in [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/c3XZ7Uoq) :

```
SELECT t.state, t.place, t.temp
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY temp DESC) as rn
  FROM table_name
  WHERE state IN ('AA', 'EE')
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 2
ORDER BY t.state, t.temp DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `rank()` or `dense_rank`, this will return more than 2 top places if there are places with the same temp,

If this what you want then try this :

```
WITH cte as (
  select *, 
  rank() over ( partition by state  order by temp desc ) rn
  from mytable
)
select id, state, place, temp 
from cte where rn <=2
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vNiveJyv)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with `partition by` clause:

```sql
select
    *
from
    (
        select
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                partition by
                    state
                order by
                    temp desc
            )
        from
            table1
    )
where
    rn <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mysql 8, check out ranking functions. For example you can use dense_rank() to also account for ties.

```
WITH ranked_temps as (
  select id,state,place, temp, 
  dense_rank() over ( 
     partition by state 
     order by temp desc
  ) dr
  from table_name
)
select id,state,place,temp from ranked_temps where dr <=2
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5TJbEUDG)